# Not able to find Google Play Billing library in my android studio sdk manager

Tags: android, macos, android-sdk-manager, play-billing-library

Android SDK manager tools with no play billing library

[image]

I have updated my sdk and also done force updates still can't find this option. Please help

Comment: And why you think that it should be there? The official documentation doesn't say a word about it

Comment: I don't believe this question deserves the downvotes. Its a common mistake.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following line to the dependencies section of the build.gradle file for your app:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
}
```

This is one way to implement in app billing, the other is adding IInAppBillingService.aidl  file (Android Interface Definition Language) to your project https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html